# Android - reading out exsting locale values directories

Tags: android, locale, directory

I wonder if there is a way to read out the locale values of all existing values directories.

Let's say I've got the following directories under my res-Directory

[...]
values
values-de
values-nl
[...]

Now I need a method to get back the information that there is a locale of de and nl existing for the directory values.

Is there any way, if yes how?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 1):

Well, ideally, your app neither knows nor cares what resource sets you have. That is the whole point behind resource sets, after all -- to insulate your app from changes in resources.

That being said, one possibility is to write a script that is part of your build process that generates a file with your requested data (e.g., XML file containing the roster of resource sets) that you then read in at runtime.

Or, arrange to have a "magic value" in each set. For example, in `res/values-de/strings.xml`, you could have a `lang_de` string, and in `res/values-nl/strings.xml`, you could have a `lang_nl` string. Then, you can use reflection to iterate over your string resources and find those matching the `lang_` pattern. This may be significantly slower than the first option, particularly if you have lots of string resources.

I know of no way to interrogate the system to find out what resource sets are defined.